# Is it possible to scroll arbitrary regions in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

I am researching the possibility of using an SSH connection for hosting a real-time, text based multiplayer game.  It would be convenient for users to be able to type in "ssh mygame.com" and play in their terminal, rather than needing a custom client.

Text-based games often have a map that moves around underneath the player (and which can scroll as the player moves).  But it would be expensive to send data to redraw the entire map under the player, every step they take.  If the map could be scrolled with a series of escape sequences, and then small parts updated (e.g. player position, NPC positions, and the newly visible part of the map), that would be much cheaper to send over SSH.

I have been reading about various terminal standards and at this point I'm a little confused.  My main question is, do modern terminals typically support this functionality that I'm describing, of scrolling any region of the screen vertically or horizontally?

Looking at this site, it seems like they might not, generally speaking:  https://terminalguide.namepad.de/seq/

I guess what I'm asking about is something along the lines of this (which is not broadly implemented):  http://www.sweger.com/ansiplus/EscSeqScroll.html

There also seems to be scroll region support in the VT520 standard (search "scroll region"):  http://web.mit.edu/dosathena/doc/www/ek-vt520-rm.pdf

Comment: If you use ncurses(3) it'll manage scrolling regions for you. Whatever you do decide, do not hard-code VT220/ANSI character sequences.

Comment: Haha thanks, yeah it does look like quite the can of worms to deal with directly, and to support various types of terminals.  I am curious though if, in the ncurses implementation would be able to do this kind of scrolling in an optimized fashion, or if it would "redraw" the entire region.  (which I suppose might depend on terminal capabilities)

Comment: ncurses maintains various state and can be intelligent about redrawing only what has been changed (if you use it correctly).

Comment: I see, so it would, roughly speaking, be "diffing" the changed content and sending the updates to the user.  (which, in the case of a scrolling map, would definitely be an improvement over sending the raw data)

Comment: You're honestly worrying about minuscule amounts of data... A full screen of say 100×160 utf-16 characters is merely 32kB. It should compress down to far less than 4kB. I don't see how this becomes a relevant amount of data in even the harshest conditions. But yeah, the terminal sends essentially commands to update regions in the screen, not the full screen all the time. (Corollary: a full-screen colorful side-scroller with highly variant background is probably worse than sending things as motion-predicted video stream to a web browser, still)

Comment: DECSTBM/IL/DL (Set Top/Bottom Margins, Insert Lines, Delete Lines) are widely supported. OTOH, DECLRMM (left/right margins) is not currently supported by urxvt, VTE, and konsole, among others.

Comment: VTE will support left/right margins in its next major release (0.76), to be released in March 2024. Better late than never.